# Android floating action menu custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, material-design, floating-action-button

I am using https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button for my floating action menu. I am trying to add text to the left of the menu just like inbox. Since the menu is a custom view which handles its expanding and collapsing, what would be the best way to add text?

Answer (score 0):

Optional labels are now available (since v1.3.0 from Dec 8, 2014):

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    ...
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">


<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    fab:fab_title="Your Title" />
```